# Kafka connect sink configuration problem - "Ignoring invalid task provided offset -- partition not assigned"

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect

We are trying to run kafka connect worker, on GCP with kubernetes, with one source connector configured on Postgresql, one sink connector syncing to BigQuery, and managed Confluent kafka. Kafka topics for offsets, config and status are configured per specification with 25, 1, 5 partitions respectively, compact cleaning policy, and retention of 7 days.

Connectors are started through REST API. Source connector seams to be working fine, but sink connector after some time starts logging these warnings:

```
[2021-09-06 08:13:12,429] WARN WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Ignoring invalid task provided offset sometable-1/OffsetAndMetadata{offset=500, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''} -- partition not assigned, assignment=[com_sync_master_dev.schema.table-1, com_sync_master_dev.schema.table-0] (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
```

Furthermore, every restart of sink connector starts from the beginning, like it cannot read offset to start from.

Before the issue, broker loses connection, connector stops, then rebalance is started.

```
2021-09-09 07:55:51,291] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=database-sync] Group coordinator *************.europe-west3.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: 2147483636 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: session timed out without receiving a heartbeat response.isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2021-09-09 07:55:51,295] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Skipping offset commit, task opted-out by returning no offsets from preCommit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:55:51,295] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Finished offset commit successfully in 0 ms for sequence number 5: null (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:55:51,298] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=database-sync] Discovered group coordinator *************.europe-west3.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: 2147483636 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2021-09-09 07:55:51,300] DEBUG Putting 500 records in the sink. (com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:55:51,301] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=database-sync] Discovered group coordinator *************.europe-west3.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: 2147483636 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2021-09-09 07:55:51,302] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=database-sync] Group coordinator *************.europe-west3.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: 2147483636 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: coordinator unavailable.isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2021-09-09 07:55:56,732] DEBUG re-attempting insertion (com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.AdaptiveBigQueryWriter)
[2021-09-09 07:55:56,735] DEBUG table insertion completed successfully (com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.AdaptiveBigQueryWriter)
[2021-09-09 07:55:56,739] DEBUG Wrote 500 rows over 1 successful calls and 0 failed calls. (com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.TableWriter)
[2021-09-09 07:55:56,736] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=database-sync] Broker coordinator was unreachable for 3000ms. Revoking previous assignment Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-fd48e893-1729-4df4-8d1e-3370c1e76e1f', leaderUrl='http://confluent-bigquery-connect:8083/', offset=555, connectorIds=[master-gcp-bq-sink, master-gcp-source], taskIds=[master-gcp-bq-sink-0, master-gcp-source-0], revokedConnectorIds=[], revokedTaskIds=[], delay=0} to avoid running tasks while not being a member the group (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator)
```

Offsets for sink connector are always restarted from 0, and WorkerSinkTask is skipping last commit, logs:

```
[2021-09-09 07:29:25,177] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Skipping offset commit, no change since last commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:29:25,177] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Finished offset commit successfully in 0 ms for sequence number 1345: null (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:50:39,281] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Initializing and starting task for topics com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:50:39,300] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Sink task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:50:39,595] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Partitions assigned [com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-1, com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-0] (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:50:39,795] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Assigned topic partition com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-1 with offset 0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:50:39,817] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Assigned topic partition com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-0 with offset 0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:51:39,308] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Skipping offset commit, task opted-out by returning no offsets from preCommit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:51:39,308] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Finished offset commit successfully in 0 ms for sequence number 1: null (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:52:39,355] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Skipping offset commit, task opted-out by returning no offsets from preCommit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 07:52:39,355] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Finished offset commit successfully in 0 ms for sequence number 2: null (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
...
[2021-09-09 08:01:03,158] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Initializing and starting task for topics com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 08:01:03,168] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Sink task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 08:01:03,381] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Partitions assigned [com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-1, com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-0] (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 08:01:03,410] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Assigned topic partition com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-1 with offset 0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 08:01:03,762] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Assigned topic partition com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-0 with offset 0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 08:02:03,145] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Skipping offset commit, task opted-out by returning no offsets from preCommit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 08:02:03,145] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Finished offset commit successfully in 0 ms for sequence number 1: null (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
....
[2021-09-09 08:09:17,085] WARN WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Ignoring invalid task provided offset sometable-0/OffsetAndMetadata{offset=395300, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''} -- partition not assigned, assignment=[com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-1, com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-0] (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-09-09 08:09:17,085] WARN WorkerSinkTask{id=master-gcp-bq-sink-0} Ignoring invalid task provided offset sometable-1/OffsetAndMetadata{offset=380428, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''} -- partition not assigned, assignment=[com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-1, com_sync_master_dev.someshema.sometable-0] (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
```

Source configuration:

```
{
"name": "master-gcp-source",
"config": {
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
  "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
  "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "******",
  "key.converter.schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info":"*****",
  "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://************.gcp.confluent.cloud",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "errors.tolerance": "none",
  "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"dlq_postgres_source",
  "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor": 1,
  "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable":true,
  "errors.log.enable":true,
  "errors.log.include.messages":true,
  "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "******",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info":"***************",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://************.gcp.confluent.cloud",
  "transforms.extractKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
  "database.hostname": "hostname",
  "database.port": "5432",
  "database.user": "some_db_user",
  "database.password": "***********",
  "database.dbname" : "master",
  "database.server.name": "com_master_dev",
  "database.sslmode": "require",
  "table.include.list": "schema.table",
  "table.ignore.builtin": true,
  "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "slot.drop.on.stop": false,
  "xmin.fetch.interval.ms": 0,
  "interval.handling.mode": "numeric",
  "binary.handling.mode": "bytes",
  "sanitize.field.names": true,
  "slot.max.retries":6,
  "slot.retry.delay.ms": 10000,
  "event.processing.failure.handling.mode": "fail",
  "slot.name": "debezium",
  "publication.name": "dbz_publication",
  "decimal.handling.mode": "precise",
  "snapshot.lock.timeout.ms": "10000",
  "snapshot.mode":"initial",
  "output.data.format": "AVRO",
  "transforms": "unwrap",
  "offset.flush.interval.ms": "0",
  "offset.flush.timeout.ms" : "20000",
  "max.batch.size": "1024",
  "max.queue.size":"4096",
  "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState"
}
}
```

Sink configuration:

```
{
"name": "master-gcp-bq-sink",
"config": {
  "connector.class": "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "*********",
  "key.converter.schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info":"************",
  "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://*********.europe-west3.gcp.confluent.cloud",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "*******",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info":"****************************",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://*********.europe-west3.gcp.confluent.cloud",
  "config.action.reload": "restart",
  "topics": "com_master_dev.schema.table",
  "project": "dev",
  "defaultDataset": "schema",
  "keyfile": "{********}",
  "keySource": "JSON",
  "errors.tolerance": "none",
  "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"dlq_bigquery_sink",
  "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor": 3,
  "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable":true,
  "errors.log.enable":true,
  "errors.log.include.messages":true,
   "data.format":"AVRO",
  "upsertEnabled": true,
  "deleteEnabled": false,
  "allowNewBigQueryFields": "true",
  "sanitizeTopics": true,
  "sanitizeFieldNames": true,
  "autoCreateTables": true,
  "timePartitioningType": "DAY",
  "kafkaKeyFieldName":"key_placeholder",
  "mergeIntervalMs": "60000",
  "mergeRecordsThreshold": "-1",
  "transforms": "unwrap",
  "consumer.override.session.timeout.ms":"60000",
  "consumer.override.fetch.max.bytes": "1048576",
  "consumer.override.request.timeout.ms":"60000",   
  "consumer.override.reconnect.backoff.max.ms":"10000",
  "consumer.override.reconnect.backoff.ms":"250",
  "consumer.override.partition.assignment.strategy":"org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor", // also tried with RoundRobinAssignor
  "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
  "transforms": "RegexTransformation",
  "transforms.RegexTransformation.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
  "transforms.RegexTransformation.regex":"(com_sync_master_dev.schema.)(.*)",
  "transforms.RegexTransformation.replacement": "$2"
}
}
```

What are we missing? How to avoid invalid task offsets, and make sure that sink connector continue from previous offset?

Answer (score 0):

So in Kafka you need to configure a consumer group for a consumer of a topic to take advantage of the offset. Otherwise the failed sink will just respawn and have no idea of what offset it was reading from when it was alive the last time.

When a member of a consumer group reads from a topic it commits its progress to the broker, so that it knows where it has read from.

It seems that the offset commit is skipped for some reason, and that is why the sink always starts from offset 0.